# converting XmXs, Xms, XhXm, XsXms to milliseconds only

Tags: python

I have an external table that is build from python script. One of the columns contains time in different formats Example: 6m45s, 60ms, 2h38m, 5s34ms.
My code is

```
for Q in data['completed_queries']:
print Q['wait_time']
```

That is how I get the column from a certain webpage. I want to convert the column to milliseconds only (I created another table for it). If this was just a number it would be an easy conversion. The only thing I could think of is trying to string matching / splitting out hours, minutes, seconds if they exist then putting it all back together into a number. Any help or link to helpful documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to solve this? If you're really starting from zero, you could start off with the regular expression `re` module.

Comment: What have you considered doing?  Could you ever have to deal with XhYmZsPms as a single unit?  It seems likely that a regex-based solution could be used.

Comment: And tell us the data type of the column and what DB you are using. It would be best just to return this information from the DB if it isn't just a string. Other wise, just make if switches that would multiple the numbers by their corresponding multiplier as necessary.

Comment: The column is str. The only thing I could think of is trying to string matching / splitting out hours, minutes, seconds if they exist then putting it all back together into a number. Surely there is an easier way, beyond my knowledge

Comment: @user3508766 that's reasonable. Assume you can take a string like `XhYmZsPms` as Jon suggests, but some might be missing. If you're dealing with some "humanized" field in a non-standard format (like ISO 8601 or something), you probably won't find a ready-made parser.

Answer (score 0):

The function below is very similar to the one you are looking for. It uses regular expression to parse a string. It returns seconds (integer). All you have to do is to add miliseconds.

```
_RE_TIME = r'^(?:(\d+)h)?(?:(\d+)m)?(?:([\d.]+)s)?$'
_regexp_time = re.compile(_RE_TIME, re.ASCII | re.IGNORECASE)
def convert(timestr):
    """Convert a string with hours, minutes, seconds to seconds."""
    match = _regexp_time.match(timestr)
    if match is None:
        raise ValueError("Invalid time representation")
    h, m, s = match.groups()
    h = int(h)*3600 if h else 0
    m = int(m)*60 if m else 0
    s = int(s) if s else 0
    return h + m + s

print(convert("1m10s"))
print(convert("1H10M"))
```